# Manipulate string from command line argument

Tags: r, string

I'm calling in an argument with optparse, but I'm needing the string of the resulting argument (variable `x`) to be in the format `"test", "test2", "test3"` (quotations separated by commas):

```
# Set up command line arguments 

library("optparse")

option_list = list(
  make_option(c("--test"), type="character", default=NULL, 
              help="test", metavar="character")

opt_parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list);
opt = parse_args(opt_parser);

# grab argument into x variable

x <- (opt$pathcsv)
print(x)
```

Entering the command line :

```
Rscript --vanilla riboeclip_ma.R --pathcsv="test test2 test3"
```

output is a character type:

```
"test test2 test3"
```

However, I would like the format of the x variable to be `"test", "test2", "test3"`

My code is setup like this (notice how I have `"test", "test2", "test3"` in a vector):

```
all_counts.poly.colData <-
   data.frame(Condition =
                c("test", "test2", "test3"))
```

However, I'd like to pass that x variable instead to achieve the same result (I'm trying to automate this process).

```
all_counts.poly.colData <-
   data.frame(Condition =
                c(x))
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this, as I'm still new to R and started playing around with the command line arguments yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `splitstr` from base R to split it into a vector:

```
strsplit(opt$pathcsv, " ")[[1]]
```

If you want to add in commas you can use `gsub`:

```
gsub(" ", ", ", opt$pathcsv)
[1] "test, test2, test3"
```

If you want literal quotes use `dQuote` applied to each and then paste it back together:

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(opt$pathcsv, " ")[[1]], dQuote), collapse = ",")
[1] "“test”,“test2”,“test3”"
```

---

Based on your question you should use `strsplit` to replicate what you've hardcoded:

```
data.frame(Condition =
                c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
  Condition
1      test
2     test2
3     test3

x <- strsplit(opt$pathcsv, " ")[[1]]

data.frame(Condition = x)
 Condition
1      test
2     test2
3     test3
```

`c("test", "test1", "test2")` is a character vector and you should not try to replicate the syntax of creating a character vector by trying to add in quotes and commas. Instead, parse your command line argument directly into a character vector:

```
all(strsplit(opt$pathcsv, " ")[[1]] == c("test", "test2", "test3"))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is there anyway to simulate "test1", "test2", "test3" though?

Comment: Are you saying you want a character object like, `""test1", "test2", "test3""`?

Comment: I'm only needing the string of the parsed argument to be quotations separated by commas. "test1", "test2", "test3"

Comment: @fewidiy651 as I mentioned in my post, do not try to replicate your hardcode. Instead, you can parse your arguments directly into a vector and that will work.